# Nextjs / React parse text to html format

Tags: html, reactjs, parsing, next.js

For a specific project I use next js and react.
I have the idea to create my own component to parse text with specific condition, but I don't know if something like this already exist.

What i try to do:

To fill the content in html format.
The function can be use like this :
Parse (textNotFormatted.txt)

Use the parsing on the page where the function is call like that:
parsing.title
parsing.content

example of file.txt:

```
#title
a title
#content
a first \b line\b
a second \i line \i
```

The parser recognises this element:

- "#" the key element to delimit the data,
- "\b" for bold text
- "\i" for italic....
- detect when a line break in text without to add 
   or \n

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example:

```
import React from 'react';

const parseText = (text) => {
  const lines = text.split('\n');
  let parsing = {
    title: '',
    content: [],
  };

  let currentKey = '';
  lines.forEach((line) => {
    var line = line.trim();
    if (line !== "") {
      if (line.startsWith('#')) {
        currentKey = line.substring(1).toLowerCase();
      } else if (currentKey === 'title') {
        parsing.title = line;
      } else if (currentKey === 'content') {
        const formattedLine = line.replace(/\\b(.+?)\\b/g, '<strong>$1</strong>')
          .replace(/\\i(.+?)\\i/g, '<em>$1</em>');
        parsing.content.push(formattedLine);
      }
    }
  });

  return parsing;
};

const TextParser = ({ text }) => {
  const parsing = parseText(text);
  console.log(parsing)
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{parsing.title}</h1>
      <div>
        {parsing.content.map((line, index) => (
          <p key={index}>{line }</p>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextParser;
```

With this component, you can use it like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import TextParser from './TextParser';

const App = () => {
  const text = `
    #title
    A Title
    #content
    A first \\b bold\\b line
    A second \\i italic\\i line
  `;

  return (
    <div>
      <TextParser text={text} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The resulting HTML looks like:

```html
<div>
  <h1>A Title</h1>
  <div>
    <p>A first <strong> bold</strong> line</p>
    <p>A second <em> italic</em> line</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This approach assumes a simplified case, and you may need to expand or adjust the parsing logic based on your specific needs.